# What is the topology of $[0,1]$ in the definition of homotopy?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Here I am not asking that it is the subspace topology which it gets from real line. My main question is that what is the topology on real line (usual, discrete, ...) which gives a subspace topology on $[0,1]$.
In my view it should be discrete in the case of homotopy as each function at some particular "$t$" (singleton) is continuous, which is open in only discrete topology.
Please explain with some examples.

Comment: It is the Euclidean one. Why would it be the discrete one? The whole point is that a homotopy is a "gradual" transformation between two spaces.

Comment: Then how does the definition of homotopy implies that at each particular "t" in [0,1] we get a conitiuous map.

Comment: The restriction of a continuous function is continuous... just restrict the domain of your homotopy from $X \times [0,1]$ to $X \times \{t\}$.

Comment: It is the Euclidean one, or the order topology, either one. The order topology is probably better, but they are the same topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of homotopy, the topology on $[0,1]$ is the usual topology.  If 
$$
H:X \times [0,1] \to Y
$$
is a continuous map, then the maps $H(\cdot ,t)$ for fixed values $t \in [0,1]$ are necessarily continuous.  To see that this is the case, note that under the usual topology on $[0,1]$ and the usual product topology on $X \times [0,1]$, the "inclusion" $\iota_t: X \to X \times [0,1]$ defined by $\iota_t(x) = (x,t)$ is continuous for any $t \in [0,1]$.  As such, $p_t(x) = H(x,t)$ defines a continuous map from $X$ to $Y$ since it can be written as the composition
$$
p_t = H \circ \iota_t.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The topology of $[0,1]$ is the standard "analytic" one in homotopy. Consider the homotopy $F: X \times [0,1]\rightarrow Y$. Define $f(x)=(t-1)x$, and $g(x)=tx$ with $F(x,t)=(t-1)x+tx$. Note this is a homotopy because $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$. Now consider the open set $V\subset Y$. Since the homotopy map is continuous, we have $f^{-1}(V)\subset X \times [0,1]$, and the pre-image is open.

However, if $[0,1]$ had a different topology, such as the discrete one, every subset of $[0,1]$ would be open. But then if we let $V\subset Y$ be a closed set, the pre-image of a closed set is closed by continuity, so $f^{-1}(V)\subset X \times [0,1]$ contradicts continuity. There are other situations where we can show $[0,1]$ under the standard topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ is the correct one for homotopy theory.